# MongoDb aggregate not grouping correctly

Tags: mongodb

So what I want to do is get the total number of sport activities offered per province per type. For Berlin and Cologne the activities are Running and swimming
The output should look something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "province" : "Berlin", 
        "type" : "Running"
    }, 
    "number" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "province" : "Berlin", 
        "type" : "Swimming"
    }, 
    " number" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "province" : "Cologne", 
        "type" : "Running"
    }, 
    "number" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "province" : "Cologne", 
        "type" : "Swimming"
    }, 
    "number" : 1.0
}
```

my query looks like this, im not getting the result that i want. It shows me the provinces where Running and Swimming are activities which are not Berlin or Cologne. I tried putting the $or insinde a $and and it still didnt produce the outcome i wanted. What am I missing?

```
db.getCollection("Sport").aggregate([
    {$match: {$or: [{province: "Cologne"}, {province: "Berlin"}], $or: [{type: "Running"}, {type: "Swimming"}]}},
    {$group: {_id: {province: "$province", type: "$type"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

Comment: Does using `{"$match": {"province": {"$in": ["Cologne", "Berlin"]}, "type": {"$in": ["Running", "Swimming"]}}}` make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom Slabbaert had already great input but having no idea how your data structure actually looks it's hard to pin point the mistake. But incase the field 'type' or 'province' is an array, you would need to unwind the field first.

```
  {
    $unwind: "$type"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            {
              province: "Berlin"
            },
            {
              province: "Cologne"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              type: "Running"
            },
            {
              type: "Swimming"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer with the combination of Toms made it work! It was indeed the $unwind that I was missing. Next time ill make sure to post the data structure as well! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is within the match query, specifically the query object has the same key more than once (the "$or" key), in this case the query parser of your driver takes the last appearance of the key, Here is a simplified example:

```
const query = { score: 1, score: 2 }
results = db.find(query)
```

With query the "results" will all have `score: 2`, because the `score: 1` condition was overwritten when parsed by the query parser.
Now replace `score` with `$or` and you get the point.

You can simplfy your query by using `$in`:

```
{
    "$match": {
        "province": {"$in": ["Cologne", "Berlin"]},
        "type": {"$in": ["Running", "Swimming"]}
    }
}
```

Or your instinct to use `$and` could also work, i'm assuming there was just some syntax issue there:

```
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            {$or: [{province: "Cologne"}, {province: "Berlin"}]},
            {$or: [{type: "Running"}, {type: "Swimming"}]},
        ]
    },
}
```